# Magento 2.4.3: UI component could not be rendered because of system exception

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

Just upgraded my local machine to **Magento 2.4.3 CE**.

On the admin side, I keep getting errors:

```
A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.
```

This error happens on **every** admin page. I cleared sessions / cleared cache / restarted docker containers - same thing.

When I look into console, I see this request is failing:

```
http://magento.test/admin/mui/index/render/key/479b831574442521ca469efdc376886fde3c57d23eebbaced4a6a7f65a44bf10/?namespace=notification_area&sorting[field]=created_at&sorting[direction]=asc&isAjax=true
```

The response to that request is:

```
UI component could not be rendered because of system exception
error code: "0"
```

In Exception logs I see this error:

```
[2021-08-13 22:48:42] main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to unserialize value. at /var/www/php/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Serialize.php:35)"} []
```

Any ideas what this could be? My only guess is the notifications at the top of the Admin page where Indexer / Cache warnings show up is failing? Maybe?

UPDATE:

Looked at the piece of code the error is referring to and it's just checking if the string is null/false/empty:

[image]

It looks like I have to go hunting elsewhere for this issue. There might have been issue when I did an upgrade with Magento Framework. Going to research that next and maybe re-install it.

Comment: The best way to solve this is to debug it, you can use xdebug or just echo/print the value at that line: vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Serialize.php:35

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's a 2.4.3 issue with sessions.

Github issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33748

After setting security sessions to 0 the issue stopped.

```
Stores->Configuration->Advanced->System->Max Session Size in Admin

Stores->Configuration->Advanced->System->Max Session Size in Storefront
```

or

```
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2592000

bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_storefront 2592000
```

Not sure if this is a full solution yet. Hopefully they come up with a better solution than just setting the value to 0.

UPDATE:

Another solution is to change disable_locking in your redis session settings:

```
'disable_locking' => '0', to 'disable_locking' => '1'
```

Comment: This issue started happening at v2.3.7-p1 and v2.4.3. I implemented the same "solution" and now the backoffice loads as usual but I'm really concerned about security. According to the DevDocs, this new setting is a anti-denial of service best practice. Not sure how to find a balance between performance and security: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-session-management.html

Comment: @araujophillips the official fix for this issue is just to set it in XML to 0 (they forgot to set it to a value, that's why it was failing in the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

check if you have any extra php codes in index.php