# Stores -> Configuration side menu has disappeared (screenshot attached)

Tags: admin, adminhtml, magento2.4, magento2.4.3

I upgraded Magento from `2.4.1` to `2.4.3` and I have also upgraded my theme and related modules.
After that, the side menu of the Store-> Configuration has disappeared and it's not showing anymore.

I have been developing on Magento for years and I have not seen this behavior before. Has anyone come across such a thing?

See screenshot for details.

[image]

Comment: Try the fix from this one: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344594/magento-2-4-3-ui-component-could-not-be-rendered-because-of-system-exception?noredirect=1#comment484556_344594 I had some random errors on my side, other people had really specific issues, but mine was all JS.

Comment: Also anything in the console? Right-click -> Inspect -> Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the theme that I'm using is not yet compatible with the Magetno 2.4.3.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same strange issue, but in my case the bug appeared because of the usage such file `\view\adminhtml\layout\adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` in my custom module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <update handle="editor"/>
</page>
```

It is an [old fix for the WYSIWYG editor](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298631/90504) and it worked fine before Magento 2.4.3.